# Get true content size

Tags: javascript, jquery, size, overflow

I am wondering if its possible to get the size of the content ( not the div ) in javascript/jQuery. So if the box has a height of 200px but there is only one line of text, the content size would be around 12px.

Thanks for all your help

Comment: You meant content *height*...

Comment: Thank you for all the answers.
But in other words, I would like to know the high just before div overflows with a scrollbar...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may create a range of the element's text-contents and use the properties of the range:

```
/**
  * @param object o DOMElement
  * @return int|null boundingHeight
  **/
function fx(o)
{
  if(document.createRange)
  {
    var r = document.createRange();
        r.selectNodeContents(o);
    return r.getBoundingClientRect().height;
  }
  else
  {
    var r = document.body.createTextRange();
        r.moveToElementText(o)
    return r.boundingHeight;
  }
  return null;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/wArMN/

Comment: it also may not work in IE4 and Netscape Navigator, haven't test it yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring the font-size, you can check it with this:

```
$('div').click(function()
{
    alert($(this).css('font-size'));
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NarutoDevil/A4bK9/).

Comment: I think they want to know the font size times the number of lines, after they've been wrapped and laid out.